# Use of ENV in Dockerfile with result of command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to set the following env variable in my dockerfile, but it gets interpreted as a string. How can I do this?

```
ENV LIBREOFFICEPATH $(which libreoffice)
```

The non docker way of doing this would be:

```
export LIBREOFFICEPATH=$(which libreoffice)
```

Comment: if i understood right, you want to assign the return of a command into an environment variable. right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You can't really do this; `ENV` only takes fixed strings.  In your case hopefully you know the filesystem path inside the image already, so you don't need a complicated workaround; just set `ENV LIBREOFFICEPATH=/opt/libreoffice/bin/libreoffice` or similar.